# What games can I play on Steam on Debian?

Tags: debian, steam

I have installed Steam on my 32 bit Debian Jessie. Looking through the catalogue a lot of them have minimum requirements of Ubuntu as the OS. Can I still play the games?

Answer (score 0):

If you meet the hardware specs, and have steam installed under debian, then yes you should be just fine playing those games.

Comment: Just a side note, you may not always get the same performance due to more updated system drivers/packages. For example there are reports of better Steam performance under archlinux rather than ubuntu for this reason. Not sure how widespread this is however, or how much you'd notice.